# Visual Studio 2017/2019 Installation finished with errors - Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12

Tags: installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I tried installing Visual Studio 2017 professional on my pc and I get the following error:

> Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12

I have tried:

1. Giving full permissions on both x86 and x64 executables\ and rerun the installation without success
2. With full permissions and an administrator account running the files outside the installer but I get "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file"
3. Deleting the folders in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12* and repairing multiple times without success.
4. Complete uninstall and reinstall without success
5. Completely removed my antivirus application and tried all of the above steps without success
6. I have repeated the same steps with the installer of vs2019 and I get the same error

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Exact error:

```
Package ‘Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12,version=12.0.30501,chip=x86’ failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147467259
Details
Return code: -2147467259
Return code details: Access is denied
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By upgrading, do you mean an in-place upgrade? Don’t do that when avoidable. // Did you try downloading and installing the Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable packages manually?

Comment: If you manually download Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable from the Visual Studio website are you able to install the package?  What build of Visual Studio 2017 are you attempting to install?

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 It is build 15.9.14.and for Visual studio 2019 it is build 16.1.6
Manual download and installation of both Visual C++ 2017 and Visual C++ 2013 is successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple experiments mentioned above this is what worked in my case.

Steps to follow after the Visual Studio Installation fails with a warning:

1. Download the latest Visual C++ 2013 Redistributables x86 and x64
2. Install them without restarting Windows
3. Copy/Replace each of the executables under the following paths:
    *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio2019\Packages\Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12,version=12.0.30501,chip=x86*
    *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio2019\Packages\Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12,version=12.0.30501.1,chip=x64*
4. Open the Visual studio installer
5. Select Modify without selecting any additional features

Once Modify is selected the installation will start, the pasted files will be replaced by a _package.json file and the installation will continue with the rest of the features without any issues.

Comment: Success! This solution worked for me. One note: when i downloaded the latest Redistributables, they had a different name from the ones which existed in "C:\ProgramData...\*. For this, i used an older download of the distributables and it worked.