# Cannot install VS 2019 at all

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio

I recently had to reset my windows and cleared all my programs.
I've been trying to install Visual Studio 2019 but it's been failing.
I download the community version and when I ran the exe it brought up a window saying it was downloading then installing. Once this finished the window disappeared.
In my program files the folder for VS is there but only contains the installer folder. InstallCleanup does not seem to be helping. It also does not appear in the programs list.

After restarting my pc now when I run the exe windows just says it has stopped working.
I tried to find a copy of VS 2017 and install, which I had pre reset, and the exact same thing happened.
I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1460116/visual-studio-2017-2019-installation-finished-with-errors-couldnt-install-mic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to get this to run.
Make sure windows was fully up to date.
Reinstalled c++ redistributions with this tool : https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/visual_c_runtime_installer.html